# I try to automate signup through the google application using selenium and java. its signup but I getting some error in the console

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver, testng

I am a beginner in selenium, automation testing. I try to automate signup through the google application its signup after signup it's redirecting to deshboard but I got some error in the console.

```
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.btn.btn-circle.btn-sm.btn-google.mr-2")).click();
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,50);
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
                Set<String> s1 = driver.getWindowHandles();
                Iterator<String> i1 = s1.iterator();
                while(i1.hasNext())
                {
                    String next_tab = i1.next();
                    if (!parentWindow.equalsIgnoreCase(next_tab))
                    {
                    driver.switchTo().window(next_tab);
                    WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
                    wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']"))).sendKeys("netcse02@gmail.com");
                    driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext")).click();
                    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']"))).sendKeys("*******");
                    driver.findElement(By.id("passwordNext")).click();
                    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Unify | Dashboard"));
                    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
                    Thread.sleep(5000);             
                    }
                }
```

register with google application:

[image: register with google application]

no such window: window was already closed:

[image: no such window: window was already closed]

Comment: sounds like the window is closing after: "driver.findElement(By.id("passwordNext")).click();"  At that point your driver will be in no mans land, so switch the driver back to the first window.  (don't rely on array order, btw... use driver.getWindowHandle() to get current handle...  when switching to new tab/window use whichever handle is not that.... after done with 2nd tab/window you can switch back to the handle you saved for the current...)

Comment: I am already trying this again I got an error to suggest a coding example.

Comment: String currentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();  Do your action that opens the new window.  Set<String> allHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();  (maybe a small sleep before or expectedCondition of numberofWindowsToBe)  Then loop through... for (String handle: allHandles)... if (handle!=currentHandle){ driver.switchTo().window(handle);  }  After done there, switch back to previous: driver.switchTo().window(currentHandle);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is two generic methods that I use in my automation framework.

```
    public void waitForNewWindowAndSwitchToIt(WebDriver driver) {
        String cHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
        String newWindowHandle = null;
        Set<String> allWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        // Wait for 20 seconds for the new window and throw exception if not found
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            if (allWindowHandles.size() > 1) {
                for (String allHandlers : allWindowHandles) {
                    if (!allHandlers.equals(cHandle))
                        newWindowHandle = allHandlers;
                }
                driver.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle);
                break;
            } else {

            }
        }
        if (cHandle == newWindowHandle) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Time out - No window found");
        }
    }

    public boolean closeAllOtherWindows(WebDriver driver, String openWindowHandle) {
        Set<String> allWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        for (String currentWindowHandle : allWindowHandles) {
            if (!currentWindowHandle.equals(openWindowHandle)) {
                driver.switchTo().window(currentWindowHandle);
                driver.close();
            }
        }
        driver.switchTo().window(openWindowHandle);
        if (driver.getWindowHandles().size() == 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```